# How to set up name field for a recent in native ios app? - iOS

Tags: ios, callkit

I had a voip app which integrates call kit. Each time I call from my voip app a new recent is created in the native Phone app. I also had custom contacts in the voip app (which Phone app did not know about them). The problem is when I call a custom contact in the Phone recents app apears only phone number without the contact name. 
For example I had custom contact with phone number "sip:test" and name "Test". When I call this custom contact in the recents Phone app appears only "sip:test". 
I start an outgoind call as fallow:

```
CXHandle *startCallHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:@"sip:test"];
CXStartCallAction *startCallAction = [[CXStartCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:@"some_UUID" handle:startCallHandle];
CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:startCallAction];
[self.callController requestTransaction:transaction completion:nil}];
```

My question is there any way to modify the recent name from Phone app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't tell to provider that the name is "Test" in any moment, therefor the system doesn't know name and show number. For notify the name to system in **performStartCallAction** you need add next code:

```
CXCallUpdate *update = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
[update setRemoteHandle:[[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber value:number]];
[update setLocalizedCallerName:name];

[provider reportCallWithUUID:uuid updated:update];
```

Comment: Updating name is working, but now the "continueUserActivity:" App delegate method is not called when I tap on recent.

Comment: do you read StartCallHandle with **getStartCallHandle** in _continueUserActivity_? If not, use `NSString *handle = [userActivity getStartCallHandle];`. EDIT: and you will rcvd @"sip:test"

Comment: The **continueUserActivity:** delegate method is not called at all.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read correctly your problem, does your `didfinishlaunching` return YES when you tap on recent?

Comment: _didfinishlaunching_ method is always returned YES. Any way I made more tests and it seems to be an iOS 11 beta 4 issue, because in earlier versions every thing is working fine.

Comment: I would make some tests, but I am on my holidays and iPhone and Mac are in the office. I will tell to my coworker that test it and comment you the result today or tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @losif ! my coworker test it on iOS 11 compiled with Xcode Beta 4. Our **continueUserActivity** works correctly. Post a question about this problem and someone will helps you. I hope that you solve this problem.

Comment: Hi @AntonioM, thanks a lot for your concern. I manage to find out what was my problem. In my case I should set the CXHandle type to CXHandleTypeGeneric since my phone number is a generic value.

Comment: Yes, with CXHandleTypePhoneNumber the continueUserActivity: is not called but when I changed type to CXHandleTypeGeneric everything works as expected.